get_top250_movies() returns empty list
Why does the output of get_top250_movies in imdb return an empty list?
The following code:
pip install IMDbPY

>>> from imdb import IMDb
>>> imdb_instance = IMDb()
>>> top250 = imdb_instance.get_top250_movies()
>>> print(top250)
[]

Any idea? The above code should return a list of the top 250 movies rated by IMDb found here. The problem is the code only returns an empty array, and not the list of 250 movies.

IMDbPY is now renamed as cinemagoer. By the looks of it you are using a much older version.
Try installing the latest cinemagoer, not from the pip respository but from the Git directly using:
 pip uninstall imdbpy
 pip install -U git+https://github.com/cinemagoer/cinemagoer

Then try the code:
from imdb import Cinemagoer
ia = Cinemagoer('http')
movies = ia.get_top250_movies()
for rank, movie in enumerate(movies):
    print(rank, movie)

Please note that if you install cinemagoer using the standard
pip install cinemagoer

It will still yield an empty list as of today, 4/20 until they update the pip packages.
